# How to include FormData in Angular POST body to retrieve it from ASP.NET Core Backend as IFormFile

Tags: c#, json, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I need to send a File (image) from the frontend in Angular along with some more parameters via a POST request to my ASP.NET Core backend to upload the file to a server. The issue is that I either get an HTTP 500 Error depending on the headers I specify or, the most usual, the backend receives the FormData as an empty object.

In Angular, I first convert the Base64 image I receive to a Blob, then a File to construct the FormData (it's what the ngx-compress-image package returns when it compresses an image. Maybe there is a better way to do this too?). Then I assign the headers and send the POST request:

```
export class RestApiService {
    token: string = 'The session token';
    userID: string = 'The user ID';

    UploadImage(picAsBase64: string) {
        let blob = new Blob([picAsBase64], { type: 'image/png' });
        let file = new File([blob], Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5));

        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('pfile', file);

        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        });


        let options = { headers: headers };

        let body = {
          'paramh': this.token,
          'pfile': formData,
          'pkuserid': this.userID
        }

        return this.http.post('api/UploadFiles/UploadFiles/', body, options).pipe(map(data => { return data; }));
    }
}
```

Backend:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UploadFilesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([FromBody]JObject data)
    {
        string paramh = data["paramh"].ToString();
        IFormFile pfile = data["pfile"].ToObject<IFormFile>();
        string pkuserid = data["pkuserid"].ToString();

            ...
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
Okay, so I applied Tony's solution, but it didn't work at first. After some tests, I found the solution in declaring the IFormFile variable as a List like Nishant suggested and declaring every argument with [FromForm] like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm]string paramh, [FromForm] string pkuserid, [FromForm]List<IFormFile> pfiles)
```

**BUT** I still have an issue, because it turns out that my IFormFile has ContentType: application/octet-stream
I don't know if this is the usual and I must convert it from the backend to some image contenttype or something like that, or if it should come from the POST request as an image/png like I declared in the Angular Blob before creating the file.

[Variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHYkS.png)

Thank you all again and hope you can still help me with this last issue.

Comment: you could do it only by sending file data separate than file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use FormData for your object also like this

```
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('pfile', file);
    formData.append('paramh', this.token);
    formData.append('pkuserid', this.userID);
    return this.http.post('api/UploadFiles/UploadFiles/', formData, options).pipe(map(data => { return data; }));
```

Also you have to use [FromForm] in your controller

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles([FromForm]JObject data)
```

Comment: I tried this, but I keep getting a 500 error. I'm debugging it and it seems like the UploadFiles backend method isn't even triggered, so the error must be in the Angular part. Maybe there's something wrong with the headers, or the way I'm converting the image?

Comment: I see that you are having same controller name and same action method api/UploadFiles/UploadFiles/. Can you change you action to Upload or something else ?

Comment: I did it, but I'm afraid the result is the same: https://gyazo.com/dd1af195b98c6bd3e4d44a7da6e9e54e   Also, before, when I tried to set the header content to application/json, the backend function fired, but it received an empty object

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of 500 error ? And also can you can from postman ?

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it correctly, but this is the result of doing the post request from postman: https://gyazo.com/57ca988fd35dcc5544a04ffc8f9ea741
And you can see the screenshot of the 500 error in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Both the urls aren't matching.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to say. Can you clarify yourself please?

Comment: according to your screenshots the url you are hitting is 'api/UploadFiles/UploadImages/' and the url you are hitting in postman is 'api/UploadFilesController/UploadFiles/'.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by using IFormFile interface

> string emailModel is the Model which will be deserialized
>
> List of IFormFile files for the list of attachments

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmailAsync(string emailModel, List<IFormFile> files)
{
    EmailModel emailModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmailModelWith>(emailModel);
    List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
         Attachment attachment = new Attachment(file.OpenReadStream(), file.FileName, file.ContentType);
         attachments.Add(attachment);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Marcos please check this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-upload-images-to-an-aspnet-core-rest-servic)